# Firebird on C#: FbCommand.ExecuteReader() performance

Tags: c#, performance, firebird

I'm using C# (sharpdevelop) to access a firebird 2.5 server. This works really well. However, I have run into a performance problem.
I have two tables, Members and Transactions which store who bought what when. To see who has not been active in a while I run the following compound query:

```
SELECT * FROM members M 
WHERE exists (select 1 from transactions WHERE taDateTime >= '30.06.2013' and Memberid = M.ID)
```

So, the Members-table has a primary index on field ID and the table transactions has indeces on both taDateTime and MemberID.

```
myConnection = new FbConnection(myConnectionString);
Connection.Open();

// property of a helper class, uses myConnection
// Then when I press the Search button:
// create the sql command, because the cut-off date is passed as a dbParam
IDbCommand aCmd = new FbCommand(sql, Connection);
IDataReader aReader = aCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I now have a few 10'000 entries in members and several 100'000 entries in transactions. If I run this query in flamerobin, it takes about 2.6 sec to run. That's not thrilling, but sufficient. But If I run this query in C#, I need 3 minutes just to return from the call
  FbCommand.ExecuteReader(sql).
I've not yet even looped over the result set, this is purely the call to `ExecuteReader()`. What does that do which takes so long?

I've tried several other things, sich as limiting the number of results by adding a `ROWS` or `FIRST` clause, both with no effect. So it's not the number of results which matters. 
I've tried to split the call into 2 queries: First find the `DISTINCT(Transaction.MemberID)` and then find the Members which fit, but there are too many IDs to sensibly pass into the second query.
I've even programmed a loop which first finds the MemberIDs and then runs a `"SELECT * FROM Members where ID = xx"` for every result and that was faster than the single statement. So what is it which makes the call to ExecuteReader delay so long?

Please help, I'm really at a loss here.

Kind regards,
Hannes

Comment: Which transaction isolation do you use?

Comment: While waiting for the result, have you looked at the [MON$ tables](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SystemObjects#MONSystemTables) to see what's going on in the database?  You can see statements currently executing and sitting idle in MON$STATEMENTS.

Comment: Hiya, I only ever run one transaction at a time, so I hope this doesn't matter as I've never looked into that :) Pls correct me if I'm wrong. Regarding the MON$-tables: They look interesting, what can I learn from them? Idle statements? When would that happen? Is it perhaps possible to see the optimized statement of what I pass in? I'd love to see how flamerobin optimizes my statement, maybe that explains the diff between the performance of that vs code...

Comment: Yep, exactly.  Maybe the statement executes the same and the provider hangs before or after, or the statement text is slightly different for whatever reason.  That's why I suggested the MON$ tables -- you can see what Firebird is doing during those three minutes and narrow down where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I should have clarified this by commenting instead of posting an answer, however, as a newbie I am not allowed to ask for more information (i.e. commenting)!!!

Quoting your line "To see **who has not** been active in a while I run the following compound query:", it appears to me that the correct query in this scenario should have been...

```
SELECT * FROM members M 
where M.ID not in (select distinct memberid from transactions WHERE taDateTime >= '30.06.2013')
```

The query you have written is going to give you people who are active. Also, it loads the db server with a processing of a few 10,000 * 100,000 records.

If you are indeed looking for people who are **NOT active** after a certain date, the query I gave you should give you at least 100 times faster results then previous one. I am curious to know the outcome, please let me know in any case. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Yes, you're right. My prog allows searching for both active and inactives, so sometimes I use the NOT and sometimes the statement I wrote. Sorry for the confusion. But to answer your real question: I found that the select distinct... statement is almost 20x slower than the exists variant. I had used that originally, but found an explanation regarding the performance of such subqueires somewhere on the net which recommended using the EXIST variant as the other one does not use the existing indeces and is thus slower...

Comment: This may work today, but be warned that internally Firebird translates "not in()" to a big <> statement.  When it comes time to execute, it will be executing something like this: "(m.id <> memberid1 and m.id <> memberid2 and m.id <> memberid3...)".  There is a [statement size limit](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq197/), and one day your distinct sub query may return enough MemberId's to hit this limit.  Firebird will raise an exception.  A correlated sub query (using "not exists", which OP proposed) is the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ravi that your query itself has some edges that might need some smoothing. I am not good enough in SQL to really anticipate what happens under the hood, but just from my gut feeling I'd say your statement looks "suspicious" to me...

But that still would not answer your question alone, otherwise the execution time in Flamerobin would be just as bad as when executed from your code. For that reason I expect something in you code to be the culprit. It would be great if if you could update your post with some more code.

Things to consider:

- Is the database connection already open? Opening a connection is quite costly performance wise.
- Do you have Connection Pooling activated? Re-using connections improves performance significantly.
- Are there other resource intensive tasks/ threads or running simultaneously?
  Or are there other read/ write accesses to the database that run at the same time when you are executing that statement? Possibly several accesses are waiting for each other to finish.
- Did you bind the query results to your UI? There are hundreds of potential performance bottle necks here.
- Also, if you have profiler at hand, have a look at the execution plan. Does the statement use the indices? Or does it perform a full table scan (or whatever strange things can happen)?
- Do you `Prepare()` your command before execcution? If you are firing it several times against the database this will also give you a performance gain.

And do not forget, due to the initializations and allocations that .NET code needs when it is executed by the JIT compiler, your statement might run faster when it is run a second time. Try this and run your query a second time (or multiple times) right after the first query. Does it make difference?

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your comments. To answer your points: Yes, the connection is already open and no, there are no other queries running at the time. The result is not bound to any UI elements, I do that manually. The statement is only fired once, so Prepare() would not help me. Indeces are not used correctly, but that is a known "feature" of subqueries in firebird. That is the reason I switched to the weird statement using EXISTS rather than the neater one quoted by Ravi. But I tested all kinds of variants in flamerobin and the strange one is by far the fastest.

Comment: @user1766553: Thank you for you clarification. I still suspect your code in someway. Otherwise it would not be possible that Flamerobin was so, so much faster. Could you please post some of that code?

Comment: Earlier on the prog:
 myConnection = new FbConnection(myConnectionString);
 Connection.Open(); //property of a helper class, uses myConnection
Then when I press the Search button:
 //create the sql command, because the cut-off date is passed as a dbParam
 IDbCommand aCmd = new FbCommand(sql, Connection);
 IDataReader aReader = aCmd.ExecuteReader();
It is this last line which takes 3 minutes

Comment: sorry, formatting sucks... Copy+Paste ignores my NewLine and TABs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input, guys! Googling some keywords in your suggestions made me analyse my queries in much more detail and thus find the error: My prog "secretly" added an "ORDER BY Member.Name" clause at the end of the query, which is the culprit. I must have been looking into my eyelids to miss that :) Anyway, I found one incredibly useful article for understanding and tuning queries in firebird and can only recommend it to anyone who's interested: http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32256. Kind regards, Hannes